# Problems with the button to graph in achartengine

Tags: android, file-io, graph, achartengine, android-button

My program reads data from a txt file stored in SD memory and graphics. But it only makes the process once, when I want to select another txt and I press the graph button again, does not work. I use EsFileExplorer for select files. Any suggestions or errors you can find?

xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.37"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.01" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGraficar"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Graficar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOpen"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.54"
        android:text="Abrir Archivo" />

</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etFilePath"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:hint="Nombre del Archivo" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

The activity is

```
public class LineChart extends Activity {
public static final String TYPE = "type";
private static final String TAG = "MSG";

protected static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_FILE_TO_OPEN = 1;


private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset;
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = getDemoRenderer();
private GraphicalView mChartView;

private Button btnGraficar;
private Button btnSeleccionarArchivo;
private EditText txtArchivo;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_line_chart);
    Log.v(TAG, "Inicio");



    btnGraficar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGraficar);
    btnSeleccionarArchivo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOpen);
    txtArchivo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFilePath);

    btnGraficar.setEnabled(false);
    btnGraficar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            generarGrafica();   
        }



    });



    btnSeleccionarArchivo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openFile();
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

 if  (resultCode != RESULT_OK || data == null) {
        return ;
    } 


    Uri uri = data.getData();

    if(uri.toString().length() > 0){
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_PICK_FILE_TO_OPEN:
                // obtain the filename
                if (uri != null) {
                    txtArchivo.setText(uri.getPath());
                    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.open_message) + " " + uri.getPath(), 0).show();
                }       
                break;

        }


        btnGraficar.setEnabled(true);

    }
}




private void openFile(){
    try{
        Intent intent = getIntent("com.estrongs.action.PICK_FILE",getString(R.string.open_button));
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_FILE_TO_OPEN);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_filemanager_installed, 0).show();
    }
}

private Intent getIntent(String action,String btnTitle){

    Intent intent = new Intent(action);

    if (btnTitle != null)
        intent.putExtra("com.estrongs.intent.extra.BUTTON_TITLE", btnTitle);

    return intent ;
}


private void generarGrafica(){
    setRendererStyling();


    mDataset = getDemoDataset();

    if (mChartView == null) {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset,
                mRenderer);
        mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);
        layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
   } 
        else
      mChartView.repaint();
  }

private void setRendererStyling() {

    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setXLabels(30);
    mRenderer.setYLabels(30);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setXTitle("Tiempo");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Amplitud");
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setPointSize(20);
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true); 
    mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.BLACK); 


}


private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset() 
{
    String archivo = txtArchivo.getText().toString();
    ReadFileSDCardActivity r = new ReadFileSDCardActivity(archivo);
    Log.v(TAG, "Leyo los datos");


    double[] seriesFirstY = r.getArreglo();

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    XYSeries firstSeries = new XYSeries("ECG 1");
    for (int i = 0; i < seriesFirstY.length ; i++)
        firstSeries.add(i, seriesFirstY[i]);
    dataset.addSeries(firstSeries);
    Log.v(TAG, "creo el data set");


    return dataset;
}

private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getDemoRenderer() {
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
    XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    //r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.POINT);

    r.setFillPoints(true);

  // r.setDisplayChartValues(true);// Que despliegue los numeros
  // r.setChartValuesTextSize(25); //Tamaño de los numeros
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
   /* r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.POINT);
    r.setColor(Color.RED);
    r.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    r.setChartValuesTextSize(30);
    r.setFillPoints(true);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);*/
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.GRAY);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.GREEN);
    Log.v(TAG, "Creo el render");

    return renderer;
}
```

}

and the activity to read data from txt files is

```
public class ReadFileSDCardActivity {

public ArrayList<Double> arreglo = new ArrayList<Double>();
int contador= 0;


public ReadFileSDCardActivity(String archivo) 
{


    File file = new File(archivo);

    if(file.exists())   // check if file exist
    {
          //Read text from file
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try 
        {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;


            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                arreglo.add(Double.parseDouble(line));
               // text.append(line);
                //text.append("\n"+ "," + line );
                contador++;
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            //You'll need to add proper error handling here
        }
        //Set the text
      //  tv.setText(text);

    }
    else
    {
        //tv.setText("Sorry file doesn't exist!!");
    }

 }

public double[] getArreglo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double[] arreglo1 = new double[arreglo.size()];
    for( int i=0 ; i<arreglo.size();i++)
    {
        arreglo1[i]= arreglo.get(i);
//  text.append("\n"+ "," + contador );
    }

    return arreglo1;
}  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getDemoDataset()` on every button press. This means that you are creating a new `dataset`, but you never tell your graph that you created a new `dataset`.

I suggest that from the second button press on, you reuse the existing `dataset` and modify its contents rather than creating a new instance that you are not using anywhere.